# How to detect Redis master/slave failover?

Tags: redis

My client implementation needs to invoke a specific procedure when a Redis master/slave failover occurs. I have not seen any Jedis/Lettuce implementation of detecting a failover event.

A couple of options I have explored, but I am unsure about the implementation details yet:

1. pub/sub to +failover-detected channel
2. Check for specific exception message when Redis Sentinel could not connect to master implementation.

Anyone has some info/ideas on how this can be done programatically?

Comment: We use a standalone thread which execute `SENTINEL get-master-addr-by-name <master name>` command per 30 seconds. And compare the ip with previous loop.